# OpenGL displayes only 3 out of 12 triangles

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, jogl

I am trying to learn modern OpenGL, using the OpenGL Superbibel (6th edition). As my primary programming language is java, i am using jogl.

I have a problem, displaying a rotating cube, only 3 out of the 12 triangles are displayed. Every time the first 3 of the list (if i comment out some vertices, the next one will be used).

Main Question:

**Why only 3 out of 12 triangles are displayed?**

The result is something like this:
[image]

Vertex shader:

```
#version 420 core

layout (location = 1) in vec4 position;

out VS_OUT{
    vec4 color;
} vs_out;

uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

void main(void){
   gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * position;
   vs_out.color = position * 2.0 + vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 420 core

out vec4 color;
in VS_OUT{
  vec4 color;
} fs_in;

void main(void){
  color = fs_in.color;
}
```

Java Code:
(startup is called from the application class inside the init method, render inside the display method).

```
public class Listening9 extends GLApplication {
    private int[] buffer = new int[1];
    float aspect = 0.0f;
    float[] proj_matrix = new float[16];
    int mv_location;
    int proj_location;
    float st = 0.001f;

    public Listening9() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void render(GL4 gl4, float time) {
        time = st;
        gl4.glViewport(0, 0, GLApplication.windowSize.width, GLApplication.windowSize.height);
        gl4.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl4.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl4.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl4.glUseProgram(program);
        gl4.glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, false, proj_matrix, 0);

        float f = (float)time * 0.3f;
        Matrix4 mv_matrix = new Matrix4();
        mv_matrix.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f);
        mv_matrix.translate((float)Math.sin(2.1f * f) * 0.5f,
                             (float)Math.cos(1.7f * f) * 0.5f,
                             (float)( Math.sin(1.3f * f) * Math.cos(1.5f * f)) * 2.0f);
        mv_matrix.rotate((float)time * 45.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        mv_matrix.rotate((float)time * 81.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl4.glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, 1, false, mv_matrix.getMatrix(), 0);
        gl4.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);



        checkError(gl4, "display");
    }

    @Override
    protected void startup(GL4 gl4) {
        program = loadProgram(gl4, new String[] { "l9vs", "l9fs" }, new int[] {
                GL4.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, GL4.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER });


        mv_location = gl4.glGetUniformLocation(program, "mv_matrix");
        proj_location = gl4.glGetUniformLocation(program, "proj_matrix");
        System.out.println("MV: "+mv_location);
        System.out.println("Proj: "+proj_location);

        gl4.glGenVertexArrays(1, objects, Semantic.Object.VAO);
        gl4.glBindVertexArray(objects[Semantic.Object.VAO]);

        float vertex_positions[] = { 
                -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                 0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,

                 0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                 0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,

                 0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                 0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
                 0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,

                 0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
                 0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,
                 0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,

                 0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
                 0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

                -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
                -0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,
                 0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

                -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

                -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

                -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
                 0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,
                 0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,

                 0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f,

                -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
                 0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f,
                 0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,

                 0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,
                -0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f,
                -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f};


        gl4.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
        gl4.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
        gl4.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                     vertex_positions.length,
                     FloatBuffer.wrap(vertex_positions),
                     GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl4.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl4.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        //gl4.glEnable(GL.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl4.glFrontFace(GL.GL_CW);

        gl4.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl4.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL);

    }

    @Override
    protected void shutdown(GL4 gl4) {
        gl4.glDeleteProgram(program);
        gl4.glDeleteVertexArrays(1, objects, objects[Semantic.Object.VAO]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResize(GL4 gl4, int w, int h) {
        aspect = w / h;
        proj_matrix = FloatUtil.makePerspective(proj_matrix,
                0,
                true,
                50.0f,
                aspect,
                0.1f,
                1000.0f);

    }

    private int loadProgram(GL4 gl, String[] names, int[] types) {
        ShaderProgram shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            shaderProgram.add(loadShader(gl, types[i], names[i]));
        }

        shaderProgram.init(gl);

        int id = shaderProgram.program();

        shaderProgram.link(gl, System.out);

        checkError(gl, "initProgram");
        System.out.println("Program loaded! (" + id + ")");
        return id;
    }

    private ShaderCode loadShader(GL4 gl, int type, String name) {
        return ShaderCode.create(gl, type, this.getClass(), SHADERS_ROOT, null,
                name, "sl", null, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Listening9();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUP() {
        st += 0.001f;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure here but it might be the second parameter to `glBufferData` which is `vertex_positions.length`. IIRC you need to specify the size of the buffer in bytes, i.e. since you have a float buffer you'd need `vertex_positions.length * 4` instead.

Comment: @Thomas thank you very mutch, you are right :)
(post your answer as an answer and i will accept it)

Comment: Learning opengl directly from C++ may be hard on some steps, if you ever get stuck sometimes don't hesitate to ask help on jogl irc or forum. Ps: [this](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/tree/master/jogl-samples/src/tests) may also be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per request: the problem seems to be (see comments on question) that the second parameter of `glBufferData` expects the buffer size in bytes. Since the buffer consists of float elements you need to specify `vertex_positions.length * 4` instead of just `vertex_positions.length` (size of float is 4 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `glBufferData` is missing the data format. In C++ you should dynamically read the size with the sizeof-operator like this:

```
    gl4.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 vertex_positions.length*sizeof(GLfloat),
                 FloatBuffer.wrap(vertex_positions),
                 GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Youd should also change the type of `vertex_positions` from `float` to `GLfloat`, as this data type has the same size (4 Byte) on different machines. `float` may vary.

Comment: As far as i know, there is no GLFloat in java and size of float is fix in java (at least for the next few jears^^). I could use the SIZE_OF_FLOAT constant.

Comment: @JarlikStepsto there is a [`Float.BYTES`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#BYTES) in java8 though in previous  versions you'd need to use `Float.Size/Byte.Size`